# Is debug application a must for automation using Appium?

Tags: android, selenium, android-webview, appium

I am automating a hybrid android application. I am using google remote tools to capture objects in that given hybrid application.

**1.**
 I am able to capture objects in ***'Debugapplication.apk'*** but I am unable to capture objects(unable to inspect) in ***'productionapplication.apk'*** . The thing I wanted to know is, Should I need a debugapplication.apk to automate using Appium ?.

**2.**
I was able to see [NATIVE_APP,WEBVIEW_com.xxxxx.xxx.xx] in ***'Debugapplication.apk'*** but in ***'productionapplication.apk'*** only the [NATIVE_APP]. I would like to know what is the defference ? Is it something with the Chrome version on the device ?

Below is the code lines which I have used to change the driver context to 'WEBVIEW'.

```
driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();

 for (String contextName : contextNames) {
   System.out.println(contextNames); 
 }
```

Java Client : 4.1.2
Selenium Server : 2.48.2 
Appium Server 1.6.5

Answer (score 2):

As far as a hybrid application is concerned, you will need a debug application to run automated tests using appium, however whenever your application is in native context, that is the native stuff in the application can still be ran even if the application is not debug, but to get the webview instrumentation i.e. to run the non native content you will need a debug app.

Native app : Debug app not needed.

Hybrid app : Debug app is needed to detect web elements, native content can be used both ways.